# Discrepancy in minimum value method

Tags: awk, minimum

Linux novice here and first post.  Please forgive my lack of clarity.

I've got what I think is a simple minimum value problem with a discrepancy between two different methods: awking file by file and awking using wildcards.

I currently have about 20,000 files (and growing) where I'd simply like to find the overall minimum value in the second column.  The files all have the same prefix and are in directories one level below where I am executing my script, so I was using wildcards to do the task quickly.

Example:

```
awk 'min=="" || $2 < min {min=$2} END{print min}' */myfile.10*
```

It takes about 14 seconds to execute, but it isn't finding the true minimum.

Alternatively, I stepped through each file of each directory and I seem to find the correct minimum:

```
   min=1000000000.0
   for dir in `ls -d *run*/`; do
     minlocal=1000000000.0
     for file in `ls -1 ${dir}myfile.*`; do
       for val in `awk 'NR==1 {print $2}' $genfile`; do
         compare_result=`echo  $minlocal" > "$val | bc`
         if [ $compare_result -eq 1 ]; then
           minlocal=$val
           fileminlocal=$file
           compare_result=`echo $min" > "$minlocal | bc`
           if [ $compare_result -eq 1 ]; then
             min=$val
             filemin=$file
           fi
         fi
       done
     done
     compare=`echo $min" > "$minlocal | bc`
     if [ $compare -eq 1 ]; then
       echo "  Error finding lowest chi^2 in " $fileminlocal
       echo "  Skipping..."
     else
       echo "  Lowest value (" $minlocal ")found in " $fileminlocal
     fi
   done
```

This approach finds the overall minimum correctly, but takes 4 minutes to do so.  I understand looping through each of these files will take more time, but why would the task fail using wildcards?

Comment: I did a test on some file, your `awk` does work. For me it give the correct value.  What do you mean by `true minimum`?  You can rewrite it some: `awk '!min || $2<min {min=$2;f=FILENAME} END{print min,f}'` to get the file name.

Comment: How can we help when you does not respond?

Comment: Thanks for the reply (I had already gone to bed).

Answer (score 0):

Your awk script is probably doing a string instead of numeric comparison for every `min` value, especially since the very first statement in your script explicitly IS a string comparison. To force numeric, change it to:

```
awk 'min=="" || $2 < min+0 {min=$2} END{print min}' */myfile.10*
```

Awk treats all input as type numeric-string, it's how you use that input the first time that allows awk to figure out if it's actually a number or a string.

Comment: or just `+min` rather than `min+0`

Comment: I find the syntax `x < +y` less clear than `x < y+0`. YMMV I suppose.

Comment: awk 'min=="" || $2 < min+0 {min=$2} END{print min}' */myfile.10*
and

Comment: Sorry for the weird comments.  I'm learning the ins and outs of the site...

Unfortunately 
awk 'min=="" || $2 < min {min=$2} END{print min}' */myfile.10*
and
awk 'min=="" || $2 < min+0 {min=$2} END{print min}' */myfile.10*
give the same result.  I know the minimum is 6901.7532 (which is what is returned when searching directory by directory) but both of these methods return 6901.7536.

Comment: You're going to have to post some sample input that can reproduce the problem. I suspect one or more of your files does not follow the format you expect. Maybe they were created with DOS so they contain spurious control-Ms? Try running dos2unix on each first

Comment: While not as efficient as I'd like it to be, 

    gawk '$2!="" {print $2}' */generation.100* | sort -n | head

gives the correct minimum.  This takes about 60 seconds but I fear the sort will become a crippling bottleneck as the number of entries increases.

Comment: For the moment I'm settling on: 

    gawk '{print $2}' */myfile.* | sort -n | awk '$1!="" {print $1; exit}'

I may go back later to work on preserving the name of the file containing the minimum.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: How do you know that THAT solution will ALWAYS produce the right result? You know it gives you what you expect now but you don't know why the other solution doesn't - maybe next time the effects would be reversed. If I were you I'd dig into this now while you can see a concrete result until you figure out exactly what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting the discrepancy you mention but I would suggest that you use `sort` to solve this problem:

```
sort -n -k2 */myfile.10*
```

performs a numerical sort, using the second column as the key. `sort` will output all of the lines in all your files, so maybe you could use awk to only print the value you are interested in:

```
sort -n -k2 */myfile.10* | awk 'NR==1 {print $2; exit}'
```

Would print the value in the second column of the first line and then exit.

Comment: This does work but I suspect it is much less efficient than using awk to do the whole thing as it requires sorting the _whole_ list rather than just obtaining the minimum value. I'll leave it here as it is a valid solution but I would recommend against using for large amounts of data.